# Own booking script

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm making my own booking system and the main script that denies storing data in DB is not working. The script itself:

```html
          <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Rules\Taken;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;

class orderController extends Controller {


    // Create Contact Form
    public function setOrder(Request $request) {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    // Store Contact Form data
    public function order(Request $request)
    {


        $request->validate([
                'name' => [
                    'required',
                ],
                'phone' => [
                    'required',
                ],
                'orderdatestart' => [
                    'required', 'date_format:Y-m-d', new Taken(),
                ],
                'orderdateend' => [
                    'required', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'after:orderdatestart', new Taken(),
                ]
            ]
        );




// The main script that s not working ----->


    if (Order::where([
            ['orderdatestart', '<=', $request['orderdatestart']],
            ['orderdateend', '>=', $request['orderdateend']]
        ])) {
            return "i wont let  you do this >:(";
        }else{
          
Order::create($request->all());
        }





    }
}
```

And I have this Schema of DB

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->date('orderdatestart');
            $table->date('orderdateend');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    }
}
```

And I even have routes but I don't think that there s any problems with them

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



// Render in view
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'orderController@setOrder'
]);

// Post form data
Route::post('/', [
    'uses' => 'orderController@order',
    'as' => 'order.store'
]);
```

I can show the model too

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['name', 'phone', 'orderdatestart', 'orderdateend'];
}
```

The script that I marked as main just always display me I won't let you do this >:(

I need when one visiter has booked some date this date will be blocked from booking

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Do you see in error messages?

Comment: naah. It just always display me I wont let you book this >:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
if(!empty($bookedDate and $bookedDate2)){
```

Looks very suspicious; should that be something like:

```
if(!empty($bookedDate) or !empty($bookedDate2)){
```

You want to refuse to book if either date is not empty.

Comment: I changed this so, check out now, maybe, I have done sth wrong